# Trying to centre main banner with responsive text aligned left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to centre my banner img that is right underneath the nav bar. I want to put text on it aligned left.
I've been able to do that BUT the text on the image is not responsive at all. How do I make it so that the text changes size when browser changes size? Also, I think my CSS is all over the place so if you have any advice on that it would be much appreciated!

Here is the markup:

```css
.topimage img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1 {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: #272727;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: normal;
  left: 650px;
  top: 250px;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, arial, serif;
}

.maintitle p {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: #272727;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  left: 650px;
  top: 390px;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, arial, serif;
}

.maintitle ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.maintitle li {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: #272727;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 650px;
  top: 470px;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, arial, serif;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: #272727;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #272727;
}

.maintitle a:hover {
  background-color: #6db618;
  border-color: #6db618;
  color: white;
}

.maintitle li:hover {
  background-color: #6db618;
  border-color: #6db618;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topimage">
  <img alt="plant" src="images/main.png" />
</div>
<div class="maintitle">

  <h1>Marketing Communications & <br> Digital Design</h1>
  <p>Marketing enthusiast who has also ventured into the digital design world. Combining <br> strategy with creativity is essential in my books!</p>
  <ul>
    <li class="aboutme"><a id="aboutmelink" href="#about">My Story</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PnHV.jpg)

Comment: If you just want the text to change size, [use `vw` units](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Comment: css tip: try not to use elemental selectors, they're quite expensive - try to remember css matches everything from right to left, so for example, your `.maintitle li` selector will match all elements for `li` and then look to see which of those elements are within an element with a class of maintitle.  This means on a page with many li, it will be grabbing them all before filtering

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here. Yet, the most important is your use of `absolute` positioning. It's completely unnecessary. All you really need to do is use a `margin` of `auto` to center the elements.

In this case, instead of positioning `h1`, `p` and `ul` separately, we can move them into a wrapper element.

If you want to shrink the actual font size according to screen width, use something along the lines of `font-size: 10vw;`

```css
.wrap{
  margin: 200px auto 0;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.topimage img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1 {
  z-index: 100;
  color: #272727;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: normal;
  top: 250px;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, arial, serif;
}

.maintitle p {
  z-index: 100;
  color: #272727;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  top: 390px;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, arial, serif;
}

.maintitle ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.maintitle li {
  z-index: 100;
  color: #272727;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, arial, serif;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: #272727;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #272727;
}

.maintitle a:hover {
  background-color: #6db618;
  border-color: #6db618;
  color: white;
}

.maintitle li:hover {
  background-color: #6db618;
  border-color: #6db618;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topimage">
  <img alt="plant" src="images/main.png" />
</div>
<div class="maintitle">

  <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Marketing Communications & <br> Digital Design</h1>
    <p>Marketing enthusiast who has also ventured into the digital design world. Combining <br> strategy with creativity is essential in my books!</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="aboutme"><a id="aboutmelink" href="#about">My Story</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #272727;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, arial, serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2%;
}

.topimage img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.maintitle h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #272727;
  font-size: 8vw;
}

.maintitle p {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  color: #272727;
  font-size: 4vw;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.maintitle ul li {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  color: #272727;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #272727;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
}
.maintitle ul li:hover {
  background-color: #6db618;
  border-color: #6db618;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="topimage">
    <img alt="plant" src="images/main.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="maintitle">
    <h1>Marketing Communications &amp;<br>Digital Design</h1>
    <p>Marketing enthusiast who has also ventured into the digital design world. Combining <br> strategy with creativity is essential in my books!</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="aboutme"><a id="aboutmelink" href="#about">My Story</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have understand it wrong, but if you want to have a background image with text over it, you can use a background-image in CSS.

```
<div class="banner">
  <div class="maintitle">
    <h1>Marketing Communications & <br> Digital Design</h1>
    <p>Marketing enthusiast who has also ventured into the digital design 
    world. Combining <br> strategy with creativity is essential in my books!</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="aboutme"><a id="aboutmelink" href="#about">My Story</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then the CSS

```
.banner {
  background-image:url('images/main.jpg');
  background-position:center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.maintitle {
  width:100%;
  blahblahblah
... }
```